# JAWS not reading the correct dynatree item in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, accessibility, screen-readers, dynatree

I’ve run into a problem with Internet explorer 9 and JAWS when using the dynatree tree control with checkboxes.

My problem is when the user presses the spacebar the currently focused item is checked and selected but a random item is read somewhere else in the list.

The documentation I found on JAWS has spacebar only responsible for selecting and checking a list item or checkbox. I couldn’t find anything about the spacebar having navigational capabilities without the addition of a modifier key like ctrl. http://www.freedomscientific.com/doccenter/archives/training/JAWSKeystrokes.htm

I've updated dynatree to match the specification for tree-view from http://www.w3.org/WAI/PF/aria-practices/#TreeView and but only have direction arrows, home and end for keyboard interaction implemented.

The tree view is working fine with nvda coupled with IE9, Chrome, Firefox, opera, and safari as well as JAWS paired with Firefox and Chrome.